# How does one migrate a Gerrit 3.0 project from one Gerrit 3.0 server to another Gerrit 3.0 server and maintain the change metadata?

Tags: git, migration, gerrit

I'm looking for a native way to simply transfer projects from one Gerrit server (server A) running 3.X to another Gerrit server running 3.X (server B) BUT, I need to keep the change meta-data from server A as it flows into server B. The end result is a fully merged set of Gerrit servers that currently host vastly different code bases.

I am familiar with the Gerrit Importer plugin, but it appears that it has been broken since 2.16:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=10353

I can create new projects in server B and push the code to them, but the meta-data does not come along with it, which I would have expected since it's stored in the git repository. (I could be missing something here)

I have also copied the repositories from back-end of server A to back-end of server B in attempt to get Gerrit to recognize the full swath of repositories. This works, but it requires me to change the server ID of server B to server A's server ID in order to view the changes in the UI. This would be fine, but once the server ID is changed to server A's ID, server B's changes do not load in the UI.

Hoping for some direction with this, or that someone can point out some blatant error that I've missed in my attempts above.